# How to improve a function to convert multiple ggplot plots that are made from Patchwork syntax to a plotly plot easily

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggplotly, gridextra

Hi everyone I have been doing some EDA can using Plotly helps a lot with this. Most often I use ggplot for the main plotting and then convert via the `plotly::ggplotly` function. This works for most of the cases except when different plots are grid arranged. For this, I used the patchwork package for testing the grid-arranged ggplot(**example -** `barplot + scatterplot + boxplot`) plots and then subsetted the individual plots to make a similar `plotly::subplot` plot. This is my designed function

```
library(patchwork)

my_plotly_Function <- function(patchwork_ggplot_obj) {
    plotly_list <- as.vector(length(ggplot_obj),'list')
    for (i in 1:length(ggplot_obj)) {
        plotly_list[[i]] <- plotly::ggplotly(ggplot_obj[[i]])
    }
    plotly::subplot(plotly_list)   
}
```

This, however, is **not able to use** the patchwork packages' **special nesting** and other capabilities. Also, this becomes **very slow** for a large number of plots. How can improve this function by adding those abilities while making it run more efficiently?

Comment: {patchwork} and {plotly} are not intended to work together.

Comment: @MichaelM do know any that do?

Comment: Sometimes, instead of using multiple ggplots, one can use `facet_wrap()`, which can be translated to {plotly} via `ggplotly()`. Besides from this, you will need to write native {plotly}, I think.